# In WPF and by using Prism, how to use the MouseButtonEventArgs as a parameter of the command for a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I want to move a borderless windows, and before I adopt the Prism framework, I'd do it as follows:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MouseDown += Window_MouseDown;
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            DragMove();
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to implement this while using Prism in **MainWindowViewModel.cs** (the view model), it seems the **InvokeCommandAction** can pass the event argument for an element like button or so, but it doesn't work for a window in my case.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You Can use Attach Property. watch this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945363/9809143) in stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I got the event fired, but it seems this approach contradict the concept of MVVM pattern, which requires that the view model should not know anything about nor has any dependency upon any view elements.

In my case, I can add the Interaction.Triggers to the Window and pass the MouseButton to the view model by usng **Prism’s InvokeCommandAction**, as follows:

```
<Window
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
/>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowMouseCommand}" TriggerParameterPath="ChangedButton" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and in the view model:

```
    public DelegateCommand<object> WindowMouseCommand { get; private set; }
```

...

```
    WindowMouseCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(WindowMouse);
```

...

```
private void WindowMouse(object mouseButton)
{
    if (mouseButton is MouseButton m)
    {
        if (m == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            // DragMove();
        }
    }
}
```

if I want to call the **.DragMove()**, I need a reference of the Window... it's not the correct implementation of MVVM pattern.

So what is the best approach/practice for that?

---

I was suddenly enlightened when I saw this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426183/10958770

yes, moving a window is a **pure UI logic**, therefore it's not necessary to move it to a ViewModel... so let me just leave it in the view.

Comment: Don't strictly follow the pattern. It's called design pattern for a reason and not theory or formula. If you strictly follows every details, you will lose your perspective.

Comment: is it common that we, sometimes, have to deviate from the design pattern? @phonemyatt

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer in programming. We learn about all this pattern to solve existing problems. at the end of the day, it's about how you speak the language to solve the problem. that's why everyone is unique. You might get some idea from this article: "http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2010/03/mvvm-josh-smiths-way.html",

Comment: Thanks, that's really an inspiring article.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to implement this while using Prism

I don't know what *this* is supposed to be exactly, but I'll assume it's *how to call the view model when some event on the view happens*:

The cleanest option is an attached behavior. Alternatively, you can use an `InvokeCommandAction` variant like DevExpress' `EventToCommand` that supports forwarding the parameter.

Comment: I mean how to use the InvokeCommandAction on a Window, do you have an example code for that?

Comment: Prism's `InvokeCommandAction` won't pass the parameters. You'd put it into `<i:Interactivity.Behaviors>`, though.

Comment: I did something like this, but it doesn't work for a window:    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowMouseCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work, but it's working now, I mean, at least the WindowMouseCommand could be fired...